# Same file in different branches

Tags: git

There is the same file in my `master` and in my `welcome` branch. My master has nothing in the file but in my welcome there is a lot of things. What is going to happen when I put it all together?

Comment: What do you mean by "put it all together"?  Merge `welcome` into `master`?

Comment: When you merge branches, changes introduced in those branches will be merged. If they can't, you'll get a merge conflict. If only one branch modifies a file, those changes will be accepted without a conflict. If both branches introduced the same file, it might end up with a conflict.

Comment: Yeah what is the hierarchical level? if I can express this way

Comment: So if I have for example a file in 3 branches with the same "a" for example there will be a conflict?

Comment: But what if I have a "Hey there" in master and a hole code in other branch, what is going to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you merge two branches, Git considers three locations: the two heads (in this case, the `master` and `welcome` branches) and the *merge base*, which is usually the point at which the branches forked.

When the merge happens, Git essentially looks at each side independently and compares it to the merge base, and determines what has changed.  Git then applies both sets of changes in the result.

If one side is changed, and the other is not, Git incorporates the changes.  So if at the point your branches were forked, the file was empty, then the result of the merge will have the contents of the file.  If both sides are changes in the same area, a merge conflict will occur, and you'll need to resolve it.  There isn't a way to avoid this, since Git doesn't know what you want done in this case.

If you want to test this out and see what will happen in your case, you can create a temporary branch off of `master` and merge `welcome` into it, and see what the result is like:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git merge welcome
```

If you get into a conflicted state and don't want to continue, you can run `git merge --abort` to return to where you were.

Comment: Its all about testing it

Comment: It said when I used ```git merge --abort``` it said that there is no merge to abort

Comment: Then the merge completed successfully and there's nothing to abort.  You can switch to another branch and then delete your temporary branch.